# Metric grid annotation truncation In QGIS Print Composer

Tags: print-composer, annotation, grids-graticules, qgis-2.8

I'm recreating a map using an old x/y meter grid.

I need to truncate the grid cooridinates annotations to the thousands. So that 200000 will be displayed as 200. 220000 as 220 etc.

Is there a way to do it automatically in QGIS?
I don't see any option to manually edit the annotation, besides changing decimals or text font.

[image: grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QGIS 2.12 allows for custom grid formats, so what you are after is possible in that version.

Answer (score 1):

As Nyall said, in QGIS 2.12 and up, you can create an expression based annotation.

In the Print Composer map properties, the "grids" tab has a new option for custom annotation format, which opens the QGIS expression builder.

A simple division will suffice:
[image: Custom annotation]
[image: Reuslt]

Cool.